# Exporting multiple datasets to single Excel worksheet with EPPlus

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

I'm not able to find examples on how to export multiple data sets/tables to a single Excel worksheet utilizing the EPPlus library. When I run the codes, it returns one set that happens to be the last set. What am I doing wrong with the following codes? Thanks!

```
Dim dSets as DataSets
Dim dGrid as DataGrid
Dim dTable as DataTable
Dim sheet as String
sheet = "DumpSets"
Dim attachment as String
attachment = "attachment; filename=" + sheet + ".xlsx"
Dim xlPack as ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()
Dim ws as ExcelWorksheet = xlPack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet)
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
Response.Charset = ""

For each dTable in dSets.Tables
    dGrid = New DataGrid
    Me.EnableViewState = False

    dGrid.DataSource = dTable
    ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dGrid.DataSource, True)

    dGrid.DataBind()
Next

Response.BinaryWrite(xlPack.GetAsByteArray())
Response.End()
```

Comment: You are storing each table in the same place `.Cells(1, 1)`. If you don't want to keep overwriting the tables, you need to store each one in a different place.

Comment: Hello Blackwood, thanks for your reply. I'm a newbie with EPPlus and not familiar with most of the built-in functions that come with the library. How would your rewrite that line to prevent overwriting the tables?

Comment: You just need to decide where you want to store each table. See the answer by VDWWD for suggestions.

Comment: I am following VDWWD's suggestions. Thanks, Blackwood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Blackwood already mentioned, you always add the data in the same place.

So it should be something like this:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 1

For each dTable in dSets.Tables
    dGrid = New DataGrid
    Me.EnableViewState = False

    dGrid.DataSource = dTable
    ws.Cells(1, cnt).LoadFromDataTable(dGrid.DataSource, True)

    dGrid.DataBind()

    cnt = (cnt + 1)
Next
```

You could also add every dataset to it's own sheet.

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 1
For Each dt As DataTable In dSets.Tables
    Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = xlPack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(("Sheet " + cnt))
    ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dGrid.DataSource, True)
    cnt = (cnt + 1)
Next
```

Comment: Hello VDWWD, thank you for your response and guidance. I tried applying your first example, ws.Cells(1, cnt). It gave me a 'column out of range' error. Understandably the example applies to columns. How would I iterate through N numbers of tables and the records in them? I'm not sure if LoadFromDataTable is ideal for this.

Comment: Fixed my answer, the integer should start at `1`, not `0`. EPPlus first column is in a sheet has index `1`. But it should work if all your DataTables are in `dSets`